# Open dialog disappears after screen turns off

Tags: codenameone

When my app has an open dialog e.g. `dlg.show();` and the screen turns off by timeout the active and displayed dialog is disappeared after turning on the screen again. I'd like to have the dialog still preset.

Is there a good/recommended way to fix/workaround this behavior?

For a solution, I could imagine one of the following approaches, but could not find further information:

1. Disabling screen timeout globally for the app.
2. Disabling screen timeout for dialog specifically.
3. Using another dialog type (`modal`, `modeless` or `interaction`) that keeps staying.

Maybe there are other ways to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable that you store the state of in Preferences. Perhaps a Boolean so when the dialog shows it is true, and if someone exits the app you save it in preferences (you can use exit form action or add something to the lifecycle methods). When the app restarts, get the state from Preferences and display the dialog again if the variable is true.

You could use and integer or string if there are multiple possible dialogs that you might need to show.

Comment: Also notice that the default `stop()` method disposes dialogs when an app is suspended to prevent the default show() method from blocking on app restore. You will need to detect the situation of a dialog running and re-show it if it's truly important. You can debug this with the suspend/resume option of the simulator.

Comment: Thank you James and Shai for the two useful and fast answers. I like the solution with the Preferences. Also I didn't know about the suspend/resume option in the simulator - very handy!